# Contract location and inheritance with private variables

Tags: solidity, evm, inheritance

When inheriting from a contract, all functions of the parent are accessible in the deployed child's contract's namespace (contract address)
Yet when a parent's function is called they read/write from private variables in the parent itself, even though the child might have the same private variable.

When a function overrides a parent's function, it would then read from the child's variable.

How does that work, how does the EVM know which variable to read from if everything lives at same contract address?

Simple code example:

```
contract parent{ 

    uint private _num = 1; 
       
    function num() public view virtual returns (uint) {
        return _num;
    }
} 
 
contract child is parent{ 
      
    uint private _num = 0; 

    // without this overriden function, the returned value would be "1"
    function num() public view override returns (uint) {
        return _num;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think about scopes as a higher-level solution for this. but it could be easily something similar to any other language implementing inheritance and overloading.